# How do I get all of the subfolders in a folder using PnP PowerShell

Tags: pnp-powershell

How do I use the PnP PowerShell to get all of the subfolders in a folder ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to retrieve all subfolders from folder using PowerShell, you can try something like

```
$folders = Get-SPOFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl "/SPDocuments" -ItemType Folder
```

You can find the entire powershell script in details [Working With Folders On SharePoint Using PnP PowerShell](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-folders-on-sharepoint-using-pnp-powershell/)